# Unable to inject a session bean into a servlet on my bluemix app

Tags: websphere, java-ee-6, ibm-cloud

I created a simple Java EE app in bluemix and deployed it. Then I created session bean and a servlet. I am unable to access the session bean method from Servlet.

Anybody has done this on bluemix?

here is my servlet code...

```
package nags.test.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import nags.test.ejb.NagseSessionBean;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class TestServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/TestServlet")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EJB
NagseSessionBean nagsBean;
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public TestServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doService(request, response);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doService(request, response);
}

public void doService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse   response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("TestServlet doService Begin");
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">");

    out.println("<title>Nags HTML from Servlet</title>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body bgcolor=\"white\">");
    out.println("<h1> This is Nags HTML5 PAge </h1>");
    if (nagsBean == null){
        System.out.println("TestServlet doService Unable to inject EJB");
    }else{
        System.out.println("TestServlet doService Able to inject EJB");
        String helloString = nagsBean.sayHello("Nagarjun");
        if (helloString == null){
            out.println("<h1> No Response from Session Bean </h1>");
        }else {
            out.println("<h1> helloString </h1>");
        }
    }

    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
    System.out.println("TestServlet doService End");
    //out.flush();
    //out.close();
}


}
```

Comment: Any errors in the logs? `cf logs <appname> --recent` Also, are you able to test it with a local Liberty server?

Answer (score 3):

Your code has no errors, and trying on Bluemix works fine. I tried it using both a Stateless and a Stateful enterprise bean.
So probably there is an error with your Bean code. 
To investigate the possible problem, retrieve the Bluemix logs using the "cf logs  --recent" command and analyse the exception thrown.